# How to make scatter plot in google sheets using 2 columns as X and Y values and the 3rd columns to get color of that point?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, scatter-plot, scatter

I have 3 columns in a google spreadsheet

```
Runs    Balls   Result
24      24      W
50      20      W
10      5       L
12      10      L
5       2       L
```

Now I want a scatter plot to be made, such that Runs and Balls are the X and Y axes, and the color of the point is determined by the values in the column Result.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be no good solutions here. Answer from Monaco works but is inconvenient in cases. I settled for adding the third column as a label for the second one.

[image: label for series]

Comment: Saved me a ton of frustration, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could separate your second column (y-value, "Balls") into two separate columns, depending on if the Result is W or L. In other words, make a chart based on three columns instead of two. This way, two different colors will be assigned automatically when the chart is generated. (Later, you can change these colors by double-clicking on the chart to get to Chart Editor -> Customize -> Series -> Format -> Color).